# After edit the quantity is not increasing from stocks as well as not decreasing from the total stocks quantity, I want it should be updated in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, e-commerce, crud

when I edit the data the quantity is not updating it is not decreasing as well as not increasing in the database, I want when I edit a data if the quantity is more than before the difference between old quantity and new quantity will be added and if the difference between old and new quantity is less than it will be decreased ... Please Help me in that
Please Help me in that

models.py

```
# models.py
from collections.abc import Collection
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def clean_mobile(self):
        mobile=self.mobile
        if len(str(mobile))!= 10:
            raise ValidationError("invalid mobile number")
        return mobile


 class Supplier(models.Model):
     
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, 
        decimal_places=2)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
        quantity= models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
        category=models.CharField(choices=CHOICES3,max_length=10)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.product_name

CHOICES3 = [('Tshirt','Tshirt'),('Jeans','Jeans'),('Jacket','Jacket'),('Shoes','Shoes'),('Watch','Watch')]
CHOICES2 = [('Polo-Tshirt','Polo-Tshirt'),('Levis-Jeans','Levis-Jeans'),('Denim-Jacket','Denim-Jacket'),('Puma-Shoes','Puma-Shoes'),('Titan-Watch','Titan-Watch')]


class Stocks(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES2,max_length=100)
    quantity = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=100)


    def __str__(self):
         return self.product_name


views.py

def supplier_dashboard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_name = request.POST.get('product_name')
        product_price = request.POST.get('product_price')
        image = request.FILES.get('image')
        quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
        category = request.POST.get('category')
        data = Supplier.objects.create(user=request.user, category=category, product_name=product_name, product_price=product_price, image=image, quantity=quantity)
        data.save()
        supplier = Supplier.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update_stocks', args=[data.id]))
    else:
        supplier = Supplier.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'enroll/supplier_dashboard.html', {'suppliers': supplier})




supplier_edit.view

def supplier_edit(request,id):
    try:
        product=Supplier.objects.get(id=id)
        if product.user == request.user:
            if request.method=='POST':
                    product.product_name = request.POST.get('product_name')
                    product.product_price = request.POST.get('product_price')
                    if 'image' in request.FILES:
                        product.image=request.FILES.get('image')
                    product.quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
                    product.category = request.POST.get('category')
                    product.save()
                    messages.success(request,"ProDuct Updated Succesfully")
                    return redirect('supplier_dashboard')
            return render(request,'enroll/supplier_edit.html',{'products':product})
    except Exception as e :
        messages.error(request," Some Error Occured ",e)     
        return render(request,'enroll/supplier_edit.html',{'products':product})

def update_stocks(request, id):
    print("------------", id)
    product = Supplier.objects.get(id=id)
    stocks = Stocks.objects.get(product_name=product.product_name)
    print(product.quantity, stocks.quantity)
    stocks.quantity = stocks.quantity - product.quantity
    stocks.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('supplier_dashboard'))
```